# ios - PageViewController inside ScrollView

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller

I have some **`pageViewControllers`** and I put them **inside `scrollView`** to scroll vertically.

Everything works fine until I **change page** of any `pageViewController` - **if the page is not first then `pageViewController` doesn't respond to vertical scrolling.**

views hierarchy:

- mainViewControllers view

  - scrollView

    - pageViewControllers view

**Finally figured out!**

I blocked gesture recogniser of `pageViewController` when it is in vertical directions.
And now it works!

**in `pageViewController.m`:**

```
- (BOOL) gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]){
        UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = gestureRecognizer;
        if(ABS([pan velocityInView:self.view].y) > ABS([pan velocityInView:self.view].x)){
            return  NO;
        }        
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Not sure how someone could upvote a question what requires random guessing as to possible causes. Show the code for how you configure the view hierarchy, any gestures you add...

Comment: @Wain added hierarchy. I dont create any gesture recognisers, just using scrollView and pageViewController and supplying viewControllers to pageViewController using dataSource object.

Comment: HI @GeorgeFedoseev, I am also using uipageviewcontroller inside scrollview. But my pageviewcontrollers page swipe got completely disabled. Can you share how did you make it work? I can share my codes if you want

Comment: I have posted a question in here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60484090/uipageview-page-turn-gestures-got-disabled-when-used-inside-uiscrollview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set the `scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = NO;` ?

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't help.

Comment: So, I understood that you have multiple `pageViewControllers` lets say one under another in a `scrollview` and you want to vertical scroll inside the `pageViewControllers`. Is that correct?

Comment: Almost. I want to scroll scrollView vertically and flip pages inside pageControllers horizontally.

Comment: i understand , but why did you said this : `if the page is not first then pageViewController doesn't respond to vertical scrolling` because you need to scroll the scrollview not the pageviewcontroller.

Comment: It seems first page has some special properties that lets scrollView to get control. I add first page viewController manually: `[pageViewController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:content[0] ] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];` as docs say, but I cant add other pages too. Other pages are supplied with dataSource.

Comment: a meant that if I start scrolling inside pageViewController (with not first page selected) than scrollView doesn't respond

Comment: because it is a `viewController` and not a `view` and I'm thinking that the touches are transferred to the `viewController` and the `scrollview` doesn't have control after you begin controlling the `pageViewController`s.

Comment: ha, just changed transition style to scrollStyle and it worked, but I want pageCurl

Comment: so it was something to do with the `pageviewcontroller` setup.

Comment: yep, seems that pageCurl-style pageViewController blocks outer container from vertical scrolling, when scroll-style doesnt

Comment: yep, solution in the description. Thank you for support!

Comment: I'm glad that i could help.