# UIPageView Page turn gestures got disabled when used inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer, uipageviewcontroller

I need to add a UIPageViewController inside UIScrollView.

**My view hierarchy is** 
UIVIewController (UIView) > UIScrollVIew > UIVIew(ContentView)

And inside that, I added my UIPageViewController programmatically.

UIPageViewController is loaded perfectly as expected. Scrollview is scrolling as well. But its page gestures got disabled by I guess scrollview.

Basically, i need UIPageView inside scrollview. I want the scrollview to scroll only vertically. And horizontal swipes should only work for uipageviewcontroller for page changing. Basically like book reader app in landscape mode. I am also using this screen to work only on landscape view.

**Here is my code**

```
class QuranLandController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var quranContainer: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    // UIPageViewController
    let controller = QuranPagerController()

    let imgWidth = 2048.0
    let imgHeight = 2732.0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let h = CGFloat((imgHeight/imgWidth) * Double(self.view.frame.width))
//        quranContainer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: h)


        addChildViewController(controller)
        controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        controller.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

        //        Translator().defaultTranslation()
        for recognizer in controller.gestureRecognizers {
            if recognizer is UITapGestureRecognizer {
                recognizer.isEnabled = false
            }
        }

        scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = false
        scrollView.delaysContentTouches = false
        scrollView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        scrollView.isExclusiveTouch = true
        scrollView.isDirectionalLockEnabled = true

//        scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false


    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        let h = CGFloat((imgHeight/imgWidth) * Double(self.view.frame.width))
        quranContainer.layout(controller.view)
        .width().top().left().right().height(h)
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: h)
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .landscapeRight
    }

    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    }

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: Why not do the other way around? like having scroll view inside PageViewController?

Comment: in that case, page curl starts from like the middle of the page.. Which looks real bad.